# Error in Serialization in DotNetNuke based portal

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, dotnetnuke

We are getting the error given below in developing DotNetNuke module at the time of Page Load. We have attached the BLL object to ViewState to persist it in the following manner.

```
ViewState[VIEW_STATE_KEY] = myBLLObject;
```

**Error Trace:**
Message:Error serializing value 'MyBLL.Framework.MyBLLClass' of type 'MyBLL.Framework.MyBLLClass.'

StackTrace:

InnerMessage:Error serializing value 'MyBLL.Framework.MyBLLClass' of type 'MyBLL.Framework.MyBLLClass.'

InnerStackTrace:

```
at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.SerializeValue(SerializerBinaryWriter writer, Object value)
   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Serialize(Object stateGraph, Purpose purpose)
   at System.Web.UI.Util.SerializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter2 formatter, Object stateGraph, Purpose purpose)
   at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Save()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.SaveAllState()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.<ProcessRequestMainAsync>d__523.MoveNext()
```

[Error Shown in Admin Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpEsi.png)

Further MyBLLClass contains only simple integer and string type properties. The screenshot is given below
[Screenshot of MyBLLClass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf5xr.png)

Comment: If you catch the exception yourself, is there any relevant information in the `.InnerException`? note: exceptions are nested: the `.InnerException` can have another `.InnerException`, all the way down to the turtles

Comment: @MarcGravell - Please explain the process to get InnerException as the error is shown in admin logs and the exception occurs after Page_Load and even Page_UnLoad events. Thus I am not able to catch the exception to view further details.

Comment: in that specific context: I don't know; good question - however, have you tried manually serializing the object type with typical values, using the same serializer - to see if it exploded in a small repro?